# jquery click is not triggering on datalist's options

Tags: jquery, html

i'm performing an jquery ajax search, and printing the response in a datalist option now i want to trigger an event on click of an option in datalist, these options are the returned vaues of ajax call, when i write something on an input field it shows the values in options but when i click on it i want to show an alert box. i've tried the following code but its not working, its not giving any errors and its not triggering any event.

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control search" list="res" />
<datalist id="res">
<option class="res-opt">Mark</option>
<option class="res-opt>Stewart</option>
        </datalist>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".res-opt",function(){
 alert("clicked");

 });});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `datalist` elements have any events, the best I can think of is to hook `input` on the text field. That'll fire for all changes, not just ones caused by clicking choices from the `datalist`, though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", "input[type=text]", function() {
    log("got input '" + this.value + "'");
  });
});
function log(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control search" list="res">
<datalist id="res">
  <option class="res-opt">Mark</option>
  <option class="res-opt">Stewart</option>
</datalist>
<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

From your comment:

> what i want is to trigger any event on click only on the options of datalist

I can't think of any way to do that. What we *can* do is trigger a handler only if the `input` event fires **and** the value of the input matches one of the `datalist` options:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var listOptions = $("#res option").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  $(document).on("input", "input[type=text]", function() {
    if (listOptions.indexOf(this.value) != -1) {
      log("Got option '" + this.value + "'");
    }
  });
});
function log(msg) {
  $("<p>").text(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control search" list="res">
<datalist id="res">
  <option class="res-opt">Mark</option>
  <option class="res-opt">Stewart</option>
</datalist>
<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

Which isn't, of course, quite the same thing, but I think it's about as close as you'll get.

Comment: @mastermind: No worries, the answer was wrong either way. I've fixed it now.

Comment: i'm already sending ajax request on the input keyup..what i want is to trigger any event on click only on the options of datalist.

Comment: @mastermind: Can't immediately think of a way to do that, the drop-down isn't really in the DOM. I've updated the answer with the closest I can think of.